# Paymill : How to do pre-authorization payment?

Tags: ios, payment-processing, paymill

I am using Paymill iOS SDK in my app to allow payment directly from my app.

I've to perform pre-authorization, I've successfully get `pre-author id`, now I've to perform transaction with that `pre-auth id`, but I am not able to find any method that allow it in SDK.

Can anyone point me to that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a transaction from an existing preauhtorization is not supported by the PAYMILL iOS SDK.

Note that it is always better to use the PAYMILL mobile SDKs only to generate a payment token and create the actual transaction/preauthorization in your backend. The transmission of the token between your app and your backend should be done over SSL. 
You can find details about this in the first chapter of the SDKs documentation: https://www.paymill.com/en-gb/documentation-3/reference/mobile-sdk/

If your use case consists of 1. creating a preauthorization and 2. create a transaction from an already existing preauthorization, you will have to implement this logic in your backend.

[Here](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-example-ios-parse-honeystore) is a  tutorial/demo app, which shows in detail exactly how to achieve the token generation on the mobile app side and the rest of the business logic in the backend.

Comment: Yes, that's all correct, Paymill support team respond the same! Thanks :)